Which model to choose for predicting presence-absence in future time points?
I have created a biological data set that consists of microbial data from 15 locations that are geographically close, and for each I have 100 time points so 1500 data points in total. For this I am trying to predict the presence or absence of a certain bacteria based on other bacteria. So my 1200 explanatory variables are species of bacteria, and these are continuous between 0 and 1 (e.g. if a bacteria makes up 50% of the bacteria found that day then it would translate to 0.5). The bacteria I am looking for is only present in the summer time, so my data set has 1420 absent and 80 present, of which the 80 present are in a group in the middle of my 1 year data set.
I would like to create a series of time lags to see if I accurately say whether this bacteria species will be present some time in the future (binary response variable), given the microbial community looks a certain way in the past. To this end I have used numerous regression models, mostly cross-fold validation random forest, which works quite well, but I believe this is because my data is non-stationary. In theory my data would be stationary for a number of years but I have only one year. I have dealt with the class imbalance using smote, and when I randomize the presence/absence of bacteria the models do not work well.
I was expecting the model to drop of some time points into the past e.g. 12 time points would be 6 weeks back at each location, so it is unlikely that this would work (I think that the microbial community from mid April should not be able to predict the presence of this bacteria at the beginning of June), but the confusion matrix for the test data set still looks like this:true negative: 257, false negative: 4, false positive: 9, true positive: 12.
Is my approach using RF for time-lag in this context fundamentally flawed? Would LTSM be more appropriate?

geography

15 locations that are geographically close

I take "close" to indicate they have similar soil and weather.
And maybe similar illumination over the course of the day,
though some may get morning shade and some get afternoon shade.
The OP did not describe an adjacency graph of
which locations are nearest to a given location,
and it sounds like the implemented model obscures that, as well.
Consider revealing such details to the model.
Perhaps the target bacteria initially appears
at one edge of the study site, and then
sweeps across nearby locations in subsequent observations.
causality

only present in the summer time, ... the 80 present are in a group in the middle of my 1 year data set.

It's unclear what helpful and harmful interactions the
various competing bacteria have with one another.
Maybe you're hoping the model will discover such chemical signaling responses?
Or maybe you're just asking the model to learn about important
exogenous variables like temperature and humidity by viewing
the ubiquitous "background" bacteria, which are affected similarly
to how the target bacteria are affected.
In which case, shouldn't you be feeding such features directly as input?
Go consult a weather API to obtain daily high, low, wet bulb temperature,
precipitation, cloud cover, hours of solar illumination, and so on.
All of your winning Random Forests should have calendar date
as the very first decision variable, given that "non-summer"
implies "no target bacteria" with 100% certainty.
You didn't show us your ROC curve, so it's hard to tell what
the model is having trouble with.
For non-summer intervals I would expect nearly a 90-degree bend,
indicating near perfect performance.
It's appropriate to look at a series of e.g. 4-week evaluation intervals
which advance a week or two at a time through the summer months,
and see how the ROC curve gradually evolves.
RF should be fine; no need for LSTM.
I cannot recommend the SMOTE technique,
as folks have had a hard time robustly reproducing that paper's results.
If you know things about the environment which you haven't revealed
to the model, definitely add such input features.
Inferring "bright, sunny day" from background bacteria populations
will be less reliable than looking at a thermometer.
